# Why can't i display my foreign key instance in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm having trouble in viewing items from a list using foreign key. I have no problems with other models, but this one seems tricky. I'm not getting something I guess... The assignement is about creating a rental place that rents movies, books and music cd's. I've created a model for Cd's and hooked a model called "songs" to it with a foreign key. Here's the code:

Models:

```py
class Cd(models.Model):
    cd_band=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cd_title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    CD_GENRE= (
        ('POP', "POP"),
        ("HIP", "Hip-Hop"),
        ("ROC", "Rock"),
        ("BLU", "Blues"),
        ("SOU", "Soul"),
        ("COU", "Country"),
        ("JAZ", "Jazz"),
        ("CLA", "Classical music"),
    )
    cd_genre=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CD_GENRE)
    cd_length=models.DurationField()

    cd_rental=models.ForeignKey(Rental, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

class Songs(models.Model):
    song=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    song_duration=models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    list_number=models.ForeignKey(Cd, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='song_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.song, self.song_duration)
```

template:

```
{% block content2 %}
{%for songs in object_list%}
    <div class="song-entry">
        <h3>{{object.song_name}}</h3>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content2 %}
```

EDIT 1:

Let me draw a bigger picture here. There is one rental space, and in this rental space we have cd's, books and movies. Thats how it looks:

```
class Rental (models.Model):
rental_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
rental_number=models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return "{} {}".format(self.id, self.rental_name)

class Book(models.Model):
    # autor, tytul gatunek, isbn, id w wypozyczalni
    book_author=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book_isbn= models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True)
    BOOK_GENRE= (
        ('SF', "Sci-Fi"),
        ("ROM", "Romance"),
        ("HIS", "Historical"),
        ("HOR", "Horror"),
        ("THR", "Thriller"),
        ("BIO", "Biography"),
        ("KID", "For kids"),
        ("FAN", "Fantasy"),
    )
    book_genre=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=BOOK_GENRE)
    book_rental=models.ForeignKey(Rental, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    class Meta:
        constraints =[
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['book_author','book_title'], name='unique_book'),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {}".format(self.book_author,self.book_title,self.book_isbn, self.book_genre)
```

So You can see that every book has a foreign key that leads to that one particular rental space. My views are as simple as it gets, cause they only lead to templates:

```
class RentalListView(ListView):
model = Rental
template_name='rental_list.html'

class RentalDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Rental
    template_name='rental_detail.html'
```

etc.

Let me show you the template for the book:

```
    <h1 style="font-size:11px; text-align:right;"><a href="{%url 'home' %}">Powrót do strony głównej</a></h1>
{% block content %}
    {%for book in object_list%}
        <div class="book-entry">
            <h2><a href="{% url 'book_detail' book.pk %}">{{book.book_title}} {{book.book_genre}}</a></h2>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

And I wanted an analogy for the songs - songs are connected to CD's via list_number variable - a foreign key with a related name=song_name. From the admin panel everything works just fine, I can add a song to a certain cd, so they are connected correctly. The songs just don't want to show up on the webpage.

Let me show You a screenshot:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmHJm.jpg)

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is no relation between CD and songs. Also, what should `song_name` be? Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/ to understand many-zo-one relstions.

Comment: can you add also your view code and specify what are you trying to render.

Answer (score -1):

For starters it looks like {{object.song_name}} should be {{songs.song_name}}

Comment: there is no song_name property/attribute in Songs model

Comment: I'm going off of what's posted in the for loop.  For 'songs' in object_list:.    Songs is your object and you would use songs.song_name to extract the song title from each item.

Comment: You would if there was such a property ...

Comment: All I'm pointing out is the inconsistency in his for loop.  If it was items you would use items.song_name.                       
 {%for items in object_list%}
    <div class="song-entry">
        <h3>{{items.song_name}}</h3>

Comment: I've tried doing "songs" instead of "object" but it doesn't change a thing. Thanks for the advice anyway :)